# Printing from Tkinter or PMW intrerface

Tags: python

I have created an interface in both Python Mega Widgets and Tkinter that is an interface to a SQlite3 database. The query results are returned as a list and disiplayed in a memo field located on the main frame of the display.

Can I create a small function that will be launched from a button that will **print from the default printer** the contents of the memo field?

something like:

```
command = printMemo  #argument within the print button


#the print function I am looking for in pseudocode
def printMemo(memo):
       print memo
```

Comment: you mean, printing on paper by using the printer?

Comment: yes.they click the button labeled print and it runs a function that prints the contents of the memo or text box to the default printer

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you are using windows or linux or mac/unix. The answer will change accordingly depending on which system you are running this python script on.

**WINDOWS**

For sending print jobs to a printer on windows, you will use `win32print` http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html

**LINUX/UNIX/MAC**

For linux/unix/mac systems, you can use the `pkipplib` library and leverage on the CUPS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUPS)  A computer running CUPS is a host that can accept print jobs from client computers, process them, and send them to the appropriate printer.
See http://www.pykota.com/software/pkipplib for CUPS-based printing.

`pkipplib` is a 3rd party library that can installed via PyPi. If you are familiar with the use of `pip`, all you need to do is to run

```
pip install pkipplib
```

and the `pkipplib` python module will be available for you to import into your script. You can then execute printing after making a connection to your linux/unix/mac CUPS printer similar to the example in the above link.  Like this:-

```
# CUPS' API
from pkipplib import pkipplib

# Create a CUPS client instance 
# cups = pkipplib.CUPS(url="http://server:631, \
#                      username="john", \
#                      password="5.%!oyu")
cups = pkipplib.CUPS()

# High level API : retrieve info about job 3 :
answer = cups.getJobAttributes(3)
print answer.job["document-format"]
# That's all folks !

# Lower level API :
request = cups.newRequest(pkipplib.IPP_GET_PRINTER_ATTRIBUTES)
request.operation["printer-uri"] = ("uri", 
                                    cups.identifierToURI("printers", "HP2100"))
for attribute in ("printer-uri-supported",                                     
                  "printer-type",
                  "member-uris") :
    # IMPORTANT : here, despite the unusual syntax, we append to              
    # the list of requested attributes :
    request.operation["requested-attributes"] = ("nameWithoutLanguage", attribute)

# Sends this request to the CUPS server    
answer = cups.doRequest(request)    

# Print the answer as a string of text
print answer
```

Comment: The code does not really address the answer for the following:

Comment: It is not a function: it does not use Tkinter. My program code must be click-able from the code of a button with command =

Comment: It must also contain reference to a memo field maybe as aparameter

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to create a text file and then use the OS print command (eg lpr on *nix). You can incorporate markup (groff or latex) if necessary) You could also create a postscript or PDF file but that's much more work!

This has the added advantage that the print command can be made configurable(environment or config file) and thus work on multiple OS.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help.
Yes, you can use win32com.client

To dispatch the file for printing you can use openpyxl to

Your data into xl spreadsheet and send them for print with default or desired printer for more information read win32com.client to send data for print

Answer (score -1):

Good question. Hope my answer will help.

Note: I use python 3.3 so thats why we need to import tkinter and Tkinter...

In the procedural code lines below, you need to define a text variable as string-variable (here it's `text1`) with `= StringVar()`.

Then when you create the entry widget (here its `text_entry`) you indicate which variable takes the value entered when the user hit the button `(.., textvariable = text1)`.

Then you create a button widget with `command =` the function (here it's `print_text(*args))` which will print the things the user typed.

Since text1 is a list (or maybe tuple, not sure) you need to use the attribute's `.get` method to get the value entered. Here its `print(text1.get())`

I added I few more things: `text_entry.focus()` puts the cursor in that widget when you run the program so that the user doesnt have to click in the entry space and `root.bind('<Return>', print_text)` allows the user to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to print.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def print_text(*args):
    try:
        print(text1.get())
    except ValueError:
        pass

root = Tk()
root.title("Little tkinter app for printing")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N,W,E,S))

mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

text1 = StringVar()
text_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 20, textvariable=text1)
text_entry.grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky = (N,W,E,S))

ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "Print!", command =
           print_text(text1)).grid(column = 1, row = 3, sticky = (E))

for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx = 5, pady = 5)

text_entry.focus()
root.bind('<Return>', print_text)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry, I afraid this doesn't answer the OP's question, which is how to actually print something to the system's default printer, not how to make a button with Tkinter that gets some text from a widget and then prints it to console using the `print()` function. Might be useful to others, though.