# Printing a canvas from Tkinter

Tags: python, printing, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have created a canvas with rectangles and labels only which I would like to print. I have only found how to save the canvas to a postscript file like so:

```
self.canvas.postscript(file="my_drawing.ps", colormode='color')
```

If necessary I would be happy to just print the whole window if that is easier.

How can I print the canvas?

This program will be used on Windows XP or 7.

Comment: Tk (and so Tkinter too) does not include ways to bring digital data to the real word, put in a nice way. If the resulting my_drawing.ps contains everything you want, then I recommend looking into ways to print that using either a Windows API or a Windows program. Such API would be the win32print, but I think it is at least problematic for handling postscript files. Easier solutions include: install Ghostscript and execute it from Python to print the output ps file; install the executable prfile32.exe if possible (http://www.lerup.com/printfile/). These are your main options.

Comment: I would take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046917/printing-from-tkinter-or-pmw-intrerface/14391826#14391826) question. It asks the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

[Send a print job to USB printer using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326042/send-a-print-job-to-usb-printer-using-python)

That person seems to have the exact same problem, answers provided.

> As far as I know, these are the two packages available:
>
> 1. [pkipplib](http://www.pykota.com/software/pkipplib)
> 2. [win32print](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html)

Comment: I managed to solve this, I would post my answer here if I manage to find what I did again