# I want to print the entire tkinter Frame or window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So I have one tkinter code.

In that I have created one label which contains some labels and images. And I want to print that whole Frame with all of its content.
I don't know how to **print the entire Frame** in the given format.

It's not compulsory to print only that particular frame it's also ok if I can be able to print all the contents of whole tkinter window.

I don't care about the extension - how it's saving the file(.pdf, .png... etc.,) but only thing i want is to print the whole window or frame.

Comment: Just to be clear, by "print" do you literally mean you want an image to be sent to a printer?

Comment: Yes! But not necessary to sent to a printer. If it's saving the file then also ok. But i just want the output in printable format

Comment: still unanswered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698738/printing-a-canvas-from-tkinter

Comment: So, you just want a screenshot of the app, with the decorations and buttons?  You  don't want, say, the contents of the textboxes in some specific format, like for printing shipping labels?

Comment: I have chosen another way.
I have created one Word file and as the content of the tkinter window changes it will reflect into the word file and i can be able to print it easier than trying to print the whole window directly